# Elasticsearch: how to filter by summed values in nested objects?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following products structure in the elasticsearch:

```
POST /test/products/1
{
  "name": "product1",
  "sales": [
    {
      "quantity": 10,
      "customer": "customer1",
      "date": "2014-01-01"
    },
    {
      "quantity": 1,
      "customer": "customer1",
      "date": "2014-01-02"
    },
    {
      "quantity": 5,
      "customer": "customer2",
      "date": "2013-12-30"
    }
  ]
}

POST /test/products/2
{
  "name": "product2",
  "sales": [
    {
      "quantity": 1,
      "customer": "customer1",
      "date": "2014-01-01"
    },
    {
      "quantity": 15,
      "customer": "customer1",
      "date": "2014-02-01"
    },
    {
      "quantity": 1,
      "customer": "customer2",
      "date": "2014-01-21"
    }
  ]
}
```

The `sales` field is nested object. I need to filter products like this:
"get all products which have total quantity >= 16 and `sales.customer` = 'customer1'".
The total quantity is `sum(sales.quantity)` where `sales.customer` = 'customer1'.
Therefore the search results should contain only 'product2'.

I tried to use `aggs` but I didn't understand how to filter in this case.
I haven't found any information about it in the elasticsearch documentation.
Is it possible?
I would welcome any ideas, thanks!

Answer (score -2):

First of all be clear what do you want as result? Is it count or query fields? Aggregations only gives **count** and for **fields** you need to use filter in query. If you want fields then you cant get filter for **sum(sales.quantity)>=16** and if you want **count** you can get it using **range** aggregation but for that also i think you can use range only in elasticsearch document fields not some computed values.
The nearest solution i can give you is as below

```
{
  "size" : 0,
  "query" :{
  "filtered" : {
    "query" :{  "match_all": {} },
      "filter" : {
        "nested": {
          "path": "sales",
          "filter" : {"term" : {"sales.customer" : "customer1"}}
                }
        }
      }
  },
  "aggregations" :{
    "salesNested" : {
          "nested" : {"path" : "sales"},
            "aggregations" :{ 
                "aggByrange" : {
                  "numeric_range": {
                    **"field": "sales.quantity"**,
                    "ranges": [
                      {
                        "from": 16
                      }]
                  }
    }
  },
"aggregations" : {
  "quantityStats" : {
    "stats" : {
      { "field" : "sales.quantity" }
    }
  }

}
}
}
}
```

In above query we are using "field": "sales.quantity". For your solution use must be able change sales.quantity with sum value of quantityStats aggregation which i think elasticsearch dont provide.